# refresh a view from event in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-events

I need to waiting (listen) for a request from client trough API route, that will send me some text, when the request is received i need to confirm it to the client and send the text to a blade view not back to the client's api.

I dont think that i can do everything in a controller logic.

So I start to dig into event/listener and I write this:

```
    class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\TextAdded' => [
            'App\Listeners\AddText',
        ],
    ];
```

then

```
    <?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TextAdded
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $testo;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($testo)
    {
        //
        $this->testo=$testo;
    }
```

and

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Listeners;

    use App\Events\TextAdded;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class AddText
    {
        /**
         * Create the event listener.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Handle the event.
         *
         * @param  TextAdded  $event
         * @return void
         */
        public function handle(TextAdded $event)
        {
            //
            return view('screen')->with('dato',$event->testo);
        }
```

and from the api, route file I call for this test route:

```
Route::post('/text', 'ScreenController@refresh');
```

thats looking for this function on the controller:

```
public function refresh(Request $r){      

        $txt='aaaaaaaaaaaa';
        event(new TextAdded($txt));
//tried to send something to view but with no success


        return true;

    }
```

Forget about how $txt is made, is just about a test.

How can I force a page from my web app to reflect this event is not so clare to me! Should I follow this road or Im far away from a solution? Im pretty sure that i cannot return to a view from an "handle" function... best regards

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#introduction

Comment: thank ill take a look!